# Change figure caption (a) ... (e) into Figure 1, ..., Figure 5

Tags: floats, captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
    \caption{...}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
    \caption{...}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
    \caption{...}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
    \caption{...}
\end{subfigure}%
    %\caption{Graph trajectories of $S$, $E$, $I$, $R$, $B$ at $R_0<1$}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the caption (a), (b), ... , (e) into Figure 1., Figure 2., ..., Figure 5. How to do it? I want the layout figure same as picture, so I'm using subfigure. But I don't know how to change the caption.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the available subcaption parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{Figure\space\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
            \caption{...}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
            \caption{...}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
            \caption{...}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
            \caption{...}
        \end{subfigure}
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}{4.4cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
            \caption{...}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %\caption{Graph trajectories of $S$, $E$, $I$, $R$, $B$ at $R_0<1$}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `minipage` instead of `subfigure`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{4.4cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{4.4cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{minipage}%
    \\[15pt]
    \begin{minipage}{4.4cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{4.4cm}
        \centering
         \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{minipage}
    \\[15pt]
    \begin{minipage}{4.4cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3.3cm, width=4.4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{...}
    \end{minipage}%
    %\caption{Graph trajectories of $S$, $E$, $I$, $R$, $B$ at $R_0<1$}
    %\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

While the answer from NBur uses per-figure counting for the sub-figures, this solution uses the global `figure` counter for labeling them.